AWS API Gateway Lambda Reverse Proxy in Javascript calling Fetch and returning the response headers does not work
If you have and AWS API Gateway with a Lambda Reverse Proxy in Javascript calling Fetch and returning the response headers to the API-Gateway it does not work.

You have to convert the headers that fetch() returns from an ES6 Map to a plain old JavaScript object, before returning them to the API-Gateway.
You probably all know this but it was driving me round the twist.
